# Footer div not keeping itself at bottom

Tags: css

The red footer gets up in the middle. How to make it keep it self at bottom? Like `clear: both` and `overflow: hidden`.

I have tried many things, is there something I am doing wrong?

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zAHDa)

The code is too large to be pasted here (30000 chars limit). Please, send me working fiddle.

*update: it works now.*

```
#footer {
  position: relative;
  height: 274px
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 274px;
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code here as well as linking to a fiddle

Comment: Do you want the footer to be visible at all time (`position:fixed`) or just be located at the bottom of the page?

Comment: no. not visible at all time. not fixed. just below the rest of the body (main div maybe)

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
#footer {
    margin:-274px 0 0;
}
```

Which is giving it a negative top margin and moving the footer up. Try removing that line. Though you may also need to tweak the content of the page. You should use the clearfix on the content so it doesnt go behind the footer.

Comment: What do you mean not working? Remove this line: `margin:-274px 0 0;` and re run the JS fiddle.

Comment: ok. its giving same results. if you have it working, please send a new fiddle link.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
#footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: no. not visible at all time. not fixed. just below the rest of the body (main div maybe)

Comment: set the margin:0px; instead of margin:-274px 0 0;

Comment: its giving same results. if you have it working, please send a new fiddle link. –

Answer (score 1):

1. `clear: both` is invalid with `position: absolute` elements, because they are out of the normal flow.
2. set a `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` style on the `div.gallery` element and it will be on the bottom of its container.

But it won't be enough for you, you should yet move your `<div class="gallery">` to move out of its container div.

Comment: setting a position: absolute; bottom: 0px; style on #footer . isnt that right. (but not working)

Comment: its giving same results. if you have it working, please send a new fiddle link. –

Comment: Yes, it is not enough, because it only positions the internal div to the bottom of the page. What you want, is to position this _unter_ the bottom of the page. The simplest solution were a little bit of restructuring of your html code: the footer divs should left the main, and get removed of the "position:" css-parameter. If I will have time, I will fix this for you, but currently I have not. If you have luck and the problem will be open after 2-3 days, I will fix this.

Comment: Until then, I think what you could best to do, is a general learning of css positioning, particularly about the exact meaning of the position:, display:, float: and clear: parameters. They are generally unusual, and hard to learn, but finally they are very simple. I suggest, start with a _very_ simple pilot html, on which you can effiziently experimenting. And when you think, you learned a lot, start to import the html elements of your current project. The first couple of html editing project is full with surprises, but finally it will be so simple as html3 was in about 1998.